# SQL: Select records based on comparison of two most recent associated records

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have a `person` table and `survey` table. `survey` is a set of attributes collected from a `person` at some point in time. Let's say `survey` has columns `address` and `marriage_status`

**How do I select all `person`s whose address or marriage status has changed in the last survey?**

Here's how I would write it if MySQL were able to magically interpret my intention:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM person
JOIN 
    (SELECT *
     FROM survey
     GROUP BY survey.person_id
     ORDER BY survey.timestamp DESC
     LIMIT 2 EACH) -- of course this part doesn't actually work. Trying to get last 2 records per person
surveys
ON surveys.person_id = person.id
WHERE surveys[0].address != surveys[1].address
OR surveys[0].marriage_status != surveys[1].marriage_status;
```

OR

```sql
SELECT *
FROM person
JOIN 
    (SELECT MOST RECENT survey FOR EACH person) latest_survey
ON latest_survey.person_id = person.id
JOIN
    (SELECT SECOND MOST RECENT survey FOR EACH person) previous_survey
ON previous_survey.person_id = person.id
WHERE latest_survey.address != previous_survey.address
OR latest_survey.marriage_status != previous_survey.marriage_status;
```

This seems like a relatively straightforward query, but it's driving me crazy. I suspect I have tunnel vision and I'm not approaching this the right way.

EDIT: I am on **MySQL v5**. Based on the first couple answers, it seems like this might be the time to migrate to v8 (among other reasons)

Answer (score 1):

So here's how I ended up doing it. It's a little long, but I think it's pretty straightforward? This felt amazing to get working.

(Note that underscores are used as prefixes in table aliases to help keep track of subquery depth)

```sql
SELECT person.*
FROM person
JOIN (
    -- Join full survey data against each 'most recent' survey timestamp
    SELECT s1.*
    FROM survey s1
    JOIN (
        -- get most recent timestamp for each person
        SELECT _s1.person_id, MAX(_s1.timestamp) timestamp
        FROM survey _s1
        GROUP BY person_id
    ) latest_surveys
    ON latest_surveys.person_id = s1.person_id and latest_surveys.timestamp = s1.timestamp
) latest
ON latest.person_id = person.id
JOIN (
    -- Join full survey data against each 'SECOND most recent' survey timestamp
    select s2.*
    from survey s2
    JOIN (
        -- to get SECOND most recent survey timestamp, do similar query, but exclude latest timestamp
        SELECT _s2.person_id, MAX(_s2.timestamp) timestamp
        FROM survey _s2
        JOIN (
            -- get most recent timestamp for each person (again)
            SELECT __s2.person_id, MAX(__s2.timestamp) timestamp
            FROM survey __s2
            GROUP BY person_id
        ) _latest_surveys
        -- Note the *NOT* equal here
        ON _latest_surveys.person_id = _s2.person_id and _latest_surveys.timestamp != _s2.timestamp
        GROUP BY _s2.person_id
    ) previous_surveys
ON previous_surveys.person_id = s2.person_id and previous_surveys.timestamp = s2.timestamp
) previous
ON previous.person_id = person.id
WHERE latest.address != previous.address
OR latest.marriage_status != previous.marriage_status;
```

Answer (score 0):

Analytic functions make your question much more tractable.  If you are not yet using MySQL 8+, then now would be a good time to upgrade.  Assuming you are using MySQL 8+, we can try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY s.timestamp DESC) rn
    FROM person p
    INNER JOIN survey s ON p.id = s.person_id
)

SELECT id
FROM cte
GROUP BY id
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN address END) <> MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN address END) OR
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN marriage_status END) <> MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN marriage_status END);
```

The above query uses a pivot trick to isolate the latest, and second latest, addresses and marriage statuses for each person.  It retains person `id` values for those whose latest and second latest addresses or marriage statuses are not identical.

Comment: Ahh interesting. I've been wanting to migrate from v5 to v8, so this is good to add to the list of reasons to do that. Though I must admit using `MAX()` in this way smells a little weird to me.

Comment: Well it's a pretty common technique used in SQL reporting.  If it allows you to avoid subqueries with `LIMIT`, then it is worth considering.

Comment: Ah that's a great point. It seems odd (to me) from a human problem-solving perspective (I would tend to minimize the results from the "subquery"). But avoiding the `LIMIT` is great of course. This feels similar to how sparse matrices and one-hot encoding make ML computation much faster, at the expense of memory (I might be way off here, not sure if these are comparable)

Answer (score 0):

It is not given, but I hope you have at least MySQL 8 or similar to have ability to use Common Table Expression. It can simplify the complex query.

The trick part is getting survey records #1 and #2 for each user. I will do it this  way: see cte1 and cte2 definition

```sql
WITH
  cte1 AS (
    SELECT MAX(x1.id) AS id, x1.person_id
    FROM survey x1
    GROUP BY x1.person_id),
  cte2 AS (
    SELECT MAX(x2.id) AS id, x2.person_id
    FROM survey x2 
    JOIN cte1 ON cte1.person_id = x2.person_id 
    AND cte1.id > x2.id
    GROUP BY x2.person_id)
SELECT 
  p.*, 
  s1.address, s2.address address2,
  s1.marriage_status, s2.marriage_status marriage_status2
FROM person AS p
JOIN (
  cte1 JOIN survey s1 ON s1.id = cte1.id
) ON cte1.person_id = p.id
JOIN (
  cte2 JOIN survey s2 ON s2.id = cte2.id
) ON cte2.person_id = p.id
WHERE 
   (s1.address <> s2.address)
OR (s1.marriage_status <> s2.marriage_status)
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hLwdHiZin4MkdUZ4aBz67H/2

**Update**: Thanks to Ian, I replaced MIN to MAX to get recent records

Comment: This appears to only show persons that have a change between the first two surveys they did (assuming lower id means earlier survey). I can see how it could be fixed though (e.g. use `MAX()` of `timestamp` in the CTEs)

Comment: Absolutely! Nice catch.

Comment: Also, the same with datetime and a bit different joins: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hLwdHiZin4MkdUZ4aBz67H/4

Answer (score 0):

This might be how you can achieve that:

```
SELECT *
FROM person
JOIN (
SELECT *,
       MAX(survey_date) latest_survey,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(survey_date ORDER BY person_id, survey_date ASC),',',-2),',',1) previous_survey, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(address ORDER BY person_id, survey_date ASC),',',-1) curadd,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(address ORDER BY person_id, survey_date ASC),',',-2),',',1) prevadd,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(marriage_status ORDER BY person_id, survey_date ASC),',',-1) curms,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(marriage_status ORDER BY person_id, survey_date ASC),',',-2),',',1) prevms
 FROM survey GROUP BY person_id
 HAVING curadd != prevadd OR curms != prevms) A 
ON person.id=A.person_id;
```

Using `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to combine the data value then separate it again and using those to compare at the end. I know there are a bunch of ways to achieve without all these, like your second example is something that I think can be done but when I think about it, it's going to be a very long query. This query however, since you're not using MySQL 8+ is much shorter but the performance of this query is a concern especially on a large table.

Comment: Wow this is very creative!

Comment: Thanks @Ian . I had a lot of practice doing it like this xD